# MultiChoice text box in html

Tags: html

Can somebody please guide me on how to create a multi-select text box in HTML (as shown below) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a option available in jquery drop down same functionality. check attached screen shot

[image]

look here for code and live example :http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm#demos/jqxcombobox/multiselect.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try this widget:

[jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos)